PL/SQL Dynamic Pivot In Clause without using procedure
I want to use dynamic pivot in PL/SQL without using procedure. I'm not good at PL/SQL and could not understand the solutions by using procedures.
My first sql statement is like this:
    select OH.Part_Product_Family PROD_GROUP,
       sum(OH.QTY_COMPLETE) PROD_QUANTITY,
       OH.DATE_APPLIED PROD_DATE
  from OPERATION_HISTORY OH, SHOP_ORD SO, CUSTOMER_ORDER_LINE_CFV COL
 where OH.DATE_APPLIED >= TO_DATE(&FIRST_DATE , 'YYYY/MM/DD')
   AND OH.DATE_APPLIED <= TO_DATE(&LAST_DATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD') 
 group by OH.Part_Product_Family,OH.DATE_APPLIED
 ORDER BY OH.Part_Product_Family

And Result is Like that:

But my manager wants to get result like excel pivot table,

I tried many times dynamic pivot in PL/SQL without using procedure, but I couldn't succeed. I tried code block below,
with A as
(select OH.Part_Product_Family PROD_GROUP,
       sum(OH.QTY_COMPLETE) PROD_QUANTITY,
       OH.DATE_APPLIED PROD_DATE
  from OPERATION_HISTORY OH, SHOP_ORD SO, CUSTOMER_ORDER_LINE_CFV COL
 where OH.DATE_APPLIED >= TO_DATE(&FIRST_DATE , 'YYYY/MM/DD')
   AND OH.DATE_APPLIED <= TO_DATE(&LAST_DATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD') 
 group by OH.Part_Product_Family,OH.DATE_APPLIED
 ORDER BY OH.Part_Product_Family)
 SELECT * FROM A
 PIVOT XML(SUM(PROD_QUANTITY) AS TOPLAM FOR PROD_QUANTITY IN (ANY))

And Result is like that:

How can I do this?

Hi Halil, there's a famous former question which has several answers including my late one at the bottom :)

You could pivot in an upstream layer, possibly Excel since you mention that. But if you can't do that and really don't want to use PL/SQL... you're using substitution variables already, but I'm not sure which client you're using. If it will this always be run in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer or some other client that understands those and can do column ... new_value ... then you could maybe (ab)use that to create a clause to substitute in - at least for small-ish date ranges...
